# make4ht finds erros when biblatex and hyperref are included in a class

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, make4ht

I've created the following class file:

```
\ProvidesClass{myarticle}[Test class]
\ExecuteOptions{}
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\RequirePackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
```

and used it in the document below:

```
\documentclass{myarticle}
\title{Test article}
\author{Test}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Test
\end{document}
```

compiling it with `make4ht` the following error message appear:

```
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
[ERROR]   htlatex: Filename Line    Message
[ERROR]   htlatex: ./article.tex    8    Package biblatex Error: Patching 'ifthen' package failed.
[ERROR]   htlatex: Compilation errors in the htlatex run
```

A piece of the .log file follows:

```
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht
version 2021-01-27-14:11
))

! Package biblatex Error: Patching 'ifthen' package failed.

See the biblatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.8 \begin{document}
```

What is causing the problem? How to solve or avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that the current version of `make4ht` (and `htlatex`) load `tex4ht.sty` package after the class is loaded. This causes that some TeX4ht configuration files are not loaded, namely files that patch the early package patches. In your case `hyperref-hooks.4ht` and `biblatex-hooks.4ht`. These are necessary for correct support of these packages.

This is the command that is used for loading of TeX4ht and the processed TeX file:

```lua
Make.latex_command = "${htlatex} --interaction=${interaction} ${latex_par} '\\makeatletter"..
"\\def\\HCode{\\futurelet\\HCode\\HChar}\\def\\HChar{\\ifx\"\\HCode"..
"\\def\\HCode\"##1\"{\\Link##1}\\expandafter\\HCode\\else"..
"\\expandafter\\Link\\fi}\\def\\Link#1.a.b.c.{\\g@addto@macro"..
"\\@documentclasshook{\\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}${packages}}"..
"\\let\\HCode\\documentstyle\\def\\documentstyle{\\let\\documentstyle"..
"\\HCode\\expandafter\\def\\csname tex4ht\\endcsname{#1,html}\\def"..
"\\HCode####1{\\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\\@ifnextchar[{\\HCode}{"..
"\\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\\makeatother\\HCode ${tex4ht_sty_par}.a.b.c."..
"\\input \"\\detokenize{${tex_file}}\"'"
```

This code originally comes from `htlatex`. The important part is this:

```
\\g@addto@macro"..
    "\\@documentclasshook{\\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}${packages}}
```

It adds `\RequirePackage{tex4ht}` to `\documentclasshook`. The problem is that it is too late when this hook is executed. Nowadays, we can use the new LaTeX hook mechanism to execute code before class is loaded. The development version of `make4ht` fixes that already, but you can use it using a `make4ht` build file:

```lua
Make.latex_command = "${htlatex} --interaction=${interaction} ${latex_par} '\\makeatletter"..
"\\def\\HCode{\\futurelet\\HCode\\HChar}\\def\\HChar{\\ifx\"\\HCode"..
"\\def\\HCode\"##1\"{\\Link##1}\\expandafter\\HCode\\else"..
"\\expandafter\\Link\\fi}\\def\\Link#1.a.b.c.{\\AddToHook"..
"{class/before}{\\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}${packages}}"..
"\\let\\HCode\\documentstyle\\def\\documentstyle{\\let\\documentstyle"..
"\\HCode\\expandafter\\def\\csname tex4ht\\endcsname{#1,html}\\def"..
"\\HCode####1{\\documentstyle[tex4ht,}\\@ifnextchar[{\\HCode}{"..
"\\documentstyle[tex4ht]}}}\\makeatother\\HCode ${tex4ht_sty_par}.a.b.c."..
"\\input \"\\detokenize{${tex_file}}\"'"
```

The changed code is this:

```
\\AddToHook"..
"{class/before}{\\RequirePackage[#1,html]{tex4ht}${packages}}
```

Compile your file using:

```
make4ht -e build.lua article.tex
```

It should compile without errors.